# Função de Ackerman - Python

Tags: algoritmo, python-3.x, funções

Bom, ainda estou aprendendo a programar em python e me deparei com exercício que não sei resolver.

Preciso escrever uma função que resolver a famosa função de Ackermann. Creio que não terei problemas com a sintaxe e a logica por traz da função em si, o problema e o calculo. Símbolos como "," e o próprio "A" me confundem. Se alguem souber como resolver ficaria grato.

[image]

PS: estou interessado em como se resolve a função , o código em python ficaria por minha conta.

Comment: `A` é o nome da função. Se tem `A` na sua definição (corpo), isso significa que ela será chamada recursivamente em algumas situações. E a vírgula simplesmente separa os argumentos - essa função `A` recebe dois números como argumento (aqui denominados `m` e `n`) e retorna um único número, dado a definição. Está mais claro? Você entende o que é uma função recursiva? (seja na matemática, seja na programação)

Comment: Sim, uma função recursiva é aquela que chama a si mesmo no "corpo" da função , certo ? Sim esclareceu algumas dúvidas , então, se hipoteticamente eu tivesse um grupo (1,3) o A seria substituído pelos mesmos e multiplicariam a sentença entre "( )" seguinte ?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer. Se você tem um par `(1,3)` e quer aplicar a função `A`, i.e. `A(1,3)`, você estaria associando ao parâmetro `m` o valor `1` e ao parâmetro `n` o valor `3`. Pela definição, `m = 0` é falso e `m > 0 and n = 0` é falso, de modo que o valor da função nesses pontos seria `A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1))`. Substituindo os parâmetros pelos seus valores, temos `A(1 - 1, A(1, 3 - 1))` que é igual a `A(0, A(1, 2))`. Então você teria que calcular `A(1, 2)` - pelo mesmo processo - e usar seu valor para calcular `A(0, ...)` - também pelo mesmo processo.

Comment: P.S. Por favor, não use o espaço de respostas para fazer comentários a respeito da pergunta. Você sempre pode comentar nas suas próprias publicações (link "comentar" embaixo da pergunta/respostas) ou - se tiver informações adicionais para melhorar a pergunta - você também pode **editar** a pergunta (link "editar") com essas informações. Pedi a um moderador que convertesse sua resposta em comentário, ok?

Comment: Ah sim agora entendi :) muito obrigado pela ajuda e desculpa pela resposta, esse e meu primeiro post e não sei muito bem como funciona. Muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: Oi, Otávio, se precisar de ajuda no uso do site, tem a área de suporte [meta]. O site tem algumas regras bem específicas que a **[help]** esclarece muito bem, é só gastar um tempinho ali e depois partir pro abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é uma função recursiva.

Você deve criar uma função `ackerman` que recebe dois parâmetros: m e n. Dentro dela, vai colocar uma sequência do tipo if... else if... else testando todos os três casos. Nos casos recursivos, deve returnar o valor de `ackerman` com os devidos parâmetros. No último else (que indica que algum dos parâmetros é negativo), lance uma exceção de parâmetros inválidos.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está a sua função! Esta função é a origem da função recursiva. Nela você tem que ter dois parametros que seguem aquelas regras que você passou na fórmula matemática, após isso, você pega os parametros e os roda afim de chegar nesta função:

```
#Função de Ackerman
calls = 0

def ackerman(m, n):
    global calls
    calls += 1
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif n == 0:
        return ackerman(m - 1, 1)
    else:
        return ackerman(m - 1, ackerman(m, n - 1))

print(ackerman(m,n))
```